# Vim select the ends of multiple lines (block mode, but where the ending column varies)

Tags: vim

Is there any way in vim that I can select the end of all these lines? (I'm only showing the end of the lines in these screenshots).

In block mode I can get them all if the bottom line is longer than the rest, but if the bottom line is shorter, the longer lines are truncated.

EDIT | I guess I can just pad out the bottom line with spaces before I select, then delete the spaces later.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

1. Put your cursor on the top-left character you want to be part of the block.
2. Enter block selection mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
3. **Select to the end of the line with <kbd>$</kbd>** (this is the step you're missing; if you move to the end of the first line using <kbd>$</kbd> then the selection will extend to the end of subsequent lines as well)
4. Move down 3 lines with <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>

There's more information in the Vim documentation's section on visual mode which you can [read online](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#v_%24), or just type `:help v_$` in Vim.

Comment: Spot on, thanks!  I didn't realize vim would treat the $ that way :)

Comment: Is a pity that I cannot give you more than 1 upvote, you really save me time, and make my day better with this, thanks

Comment: What if I want further than the end of the last line, but not quite to the end of the longest line?

Comment: I think that steps 3 and 4 should be swapped. In this case you can select lines of different lengths

Answer (score 21):

1. Click somewhere (anywhere) in the first line you wish to append text to.
2. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Down</kbd> to create an arbitrary vertical block selection that spans the desired lines.
4. Press <kbd>$</kbd> to expand the visual block selection to the ends of every line selected.
5. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to append text to every selected line.
6. Type the text you want to append.
7. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> and the text will be appended across the selected lines.

Answer (score 17):

Alternately, you can set the `virtualedit` (`:h 'virtualedit'`) setting so that, any time you're in visual block mode, you can move the cursor around even past the ends of lines. E.g. `:set virtualedit=block`.

Comment: I'd upvote you, except that `virtualedit` adds spaces past the ends of short lines. Is there any way to have it not do that?

Comment: @Thanatos I haven't run across anything to achieve that. georgebrock's answer also has that problem (but if I correctly understand your comment on his, virtualedit is almost the way to achieve what you want).

Comment: @echristopherson Yes, the "almost" is the problem: you have to open a separate buffer, strip off the trailing space, and then re-copy the text. The problem becomes impossible if the source text contained trailing space to begin with…

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking to select the very last character of every line, like if you want to add something after the quotes at the end of each line, you can do the following:

1. Put your cursor over the very last character (in this example, the last quote on the first line)
2. Enter block mode: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
3. Move down to select as many lines as you want to change.
4. **Insert at the end of the line: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>**
5. Type what you want to add and then exit Visual mode
6. You text should now be inserted at the end of each selected line!

Hope this is helpful to others like me searching for an answer similar, but not exactly the same, as the above.

Comment: Is there an option to continue editing in block mode after pressing enter (newline)? That's a neat feature in Jetbrains IDEs like PyCharm.

Comment: Step 4 was key for me. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is a new thing. But if you press `$` two times (instead one) the block goes to the end of all lines without creating extra spaces).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Tested on nvim 0.7.2.