# Selecting lines with different lengths in visual block mode

Tags: vim

I want to select a code block that consist of lines of different lengths in  visual block mode. However, since the cursor can only go as far as the end of each line, it's impossible to select the whole block of code shown below at once. Is there any tip for doing this?

[image: difficult to select]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim select the ends of multiple lines (block mode, but where the ending column varies)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772598/vim-select-the-ends-of-multiple-lines-block-mode-but-where-the-ending-column-v)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `$` to tell the visual block to select until the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of it.

Comment: @chenaren, while this works, it's quite limited. If for example you want to select until the one before last character on the line, I don't know of a way. However, in situations that I use this feature, I end up realizing that copying the whole lines and processing them with a macro is more flexible and in the end easier.

Comment: One more little question. The pasting process seems to be working in some kind of 'replace mode'. Is there any way to paste 'normally' when the content is yanked in visual block mode?

Comment: The paste is done exactly the same way other pastes are done (with `p` or `P`). The characters copied are pasted (not overwriting!) where the cursor is, of course across multiple rows and columns. Do you see any characters replaced?! Can you come up with a simple example file and the series of commands you use so I can replicate it?