# Put a selection of yanked lines at the end of other lines vim

Tags: vim

How can I put a selection of yanked lines at the end of other lines?

BEFORE:

```
11 
1 
2 
3 
10 

0.0
0.045
0.09
0
```

AFTER:

```
11 
1 0.0
2 0.045
3 0.09
10 0
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/300362/vim-how-to-paste-a-block-of-text-at-the-end-of-multiple-lines should do the job for you.

Comment: I'm stuck at using visual block mode to select all the characters in lines that have a mismatched number of columns.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772598/vim-select-the-ends-of-multiple-lines-block-mode-but-where-the-ending-column-v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a block selection until the line-end, even for an unmatched number of columns, first select vertically the first column in all lines and then press `$`.

So in your case, move the cursor to the first column of `0.0`, press `ctrl-v`, move the cursor down to the last line, press `$` and you have the block selection. Now you can cut it with `d` and paste it in the second line.

**Edit:** Since you put this `10` there, the pasting part gets a bit more complicated. I would first past the block in the right-most column that doesn't interfere with the other columns. So go to the second line, append two blanks after the `1` and then paste the block. The result will look like this:

```
11
1  0.0
2  0.045
3  0.09
10 0
```

Now you need to remove the duplicated blanks in all the lines (if they disturb you). In a simple example like this, you can do it just with another block selection. In more complicated examples you might do it with a search/replace pattern.

Comment: OP just added `10` to the destination, which might throw a wrench in this approach.

Comment: well i learnt something I never realized about block selection,  even thought it may not be the answer the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case you could also use `:g` and `:m` to reorder the lines and join them. With the cursor at the first line, do a `}dd` to delete the empty line. Cursor should be at the line with `0.0`. Now do a simple:

```
:,$g/./2m-1|j
```

[image: Vim Demo]

This works with `:g` acting as a sort of iterator over the lines. The `:g` command selects lines within a range matching a certain pattern and runs a command on such matched lines in the form `:[range]g{pattern}{command}`. Breaking it into smaller parts we have:

- `,$` this range is a short form of `.,$`, meaning from current line to the end of the file. That's why the cursor position is important.
- `/./` match lines containing any character, effectively a placeholder to say *match every line*.
- `2m-1|j` the "tricky" part, composed of two commands:

  - `2m-1` the move command, in the form `[range]m{address}`. Moves lines from *range* to below *address*. As utilized it means move the second line to address `-1` which itself is another piece of "trickery". `-1` is a short form of `.-1` which means current line position (`.`) minus one. At this point, the cursor is moved upwards to sit on the line just moved.
  - `j` join command, joins the current line to the next one with a space in between.

You can simulate what happens step by step by running `:2m-1` and then `:j` yourself on each line starting from the line with `0.0`. Again, the `:g` here works just as an iterator for these commands over those last 4 lines.

Starting with (`*` represents cursor position):

```
  11
  1
  2
  3
  10
* 0.0
  0.045
  0.09
  0
```

Running `:2 move .-1` transforms it into:

```
  11
  2
  3
  10
* 1
  0.0
  0.045
  0.09
  0
```

Then `:join`

```
  11
  2
  3
  10
* 1 0.0
  0.045
  0.09
  0
```

Move to the next line and repeat.

Comment: The basic idea here is to `:move` the second element just above the current position and then `:join` the lines. After this is done the cursor is moved downwards. Then repeated until the end of the file.

Comment: A step-by-step explanation would came in handy :)

Answer (score 2):

@GeorgP.'s answer already outlines the necessity for doing a *blockwise* delete, so that the paste does not create new lines, but appends to the existing ones. It does not mention that the blockwise delete leaves behind empty lines, so there's an additional step to get rid of them.

I needed to "cast" register contents into a certain (characterwise / linewise / blockwise) mode so often, I wrote the [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) for it. With it, you can delete the second block completely (i.e. linewise) with `4dd`, and then use the plugin's `gbp` (*go blockwise paste*) mapping at the end of the second line. Like @GeorgP.'s answer, this will make the last line contain `100` instead of `10 0`, and the same workaround of inserting an additional padding space is necessary.

However, my plugin offers many other variants of pastes, and the `gBp` pastes as a *minimal fitting (not rectangular) block with a jagged right edge. When pasting with `gBp` at the end of the line, appends at the jagged end of following lines.* This is exactly what is needed here. So, if you're willing to install a plugin, the whole operation can be done via `4dd2G$gBp`.